# Скругление уголков

Tags: css

Можно ли для скругленных уголков блоков прописывать свойство cкругления без префиксов? то есть, писать не набор свойств

```
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
-khtml-border-radius: 10px;
```

а писать просто

```
border-radius: 10px;
```

?
не будет ли из-за этого проблем с отображением в старых версиях браузеров?

Comment: нужно сначала писать свойства с префиксами, потом без префикса

Comment: спасибо. а то мне сказали, что свойства с префиксами уже лишнее, поэтому и спрашиваю, что не знаю, как правильно.

Comment: Почитайте про [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) - расширение языка css и [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) - набор подключаемых стилей, которые уже написаны сто раз. Удовольствие от написания стилей полное. Можно будет писать:

    .rounded {
      @include border-radius(10px);
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Свойства с префиксами уже не актуальны. Можно обходиться просто

```
border-radius: 10px;
```

В старых версиях браузеров, для которых предназначены эти префиксы проблемы естественно будут, но смотрим объективно - тех браузеров не осталось. ФФ и Сафари очень сложно найти тех версий, для которых нужен префикс. Работать будет в ФФ/Опера/Сафари/Хром/ИЕ9, как обічно ИЕ8 и ниже идут стороной, но там префиксі все-равно не спасали :) Мое мнение - эти префиксы аттавизм.

Comment: спасибо за объяснения!)

Comment: Ну не всегда, бывают машины на работах, где стоят прошлогодние браузеры, которые нельзя обновлять, а админ это делает раз в год, так же есть параноики, которые боятся что то обновлять и устанавливать, ну или просто блондинки, которые не понимают что такое обновление, так что вопрос спорный.

Comment: ну вконец меня запутали (

Comment: @Ъь_, тут не о чем спорить. О каких версиях браузера идет речь? 

-moz- - для фф до 4 версии... -webkit- для версий хром/сафари до 5 версии. Этих браузеров практически не осталось. Сужу по статистике 2 крупных сайтов. Доля тех браузеров менее 0.1%. 

Вообще вот [визуальное представление](http://caniuse.com/border-radius) которое поможет решить

Comment: Когда видишь блондинок на работе за такими браузерами и обновляешь им фаерфокс с 3й версии до самой свежей, а у них глаза по пять рублей от удивления, то начиниешь задумыватся над этим вопросом. Вот пример того же ВК
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 100ms linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 100ms linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 100ms linear;
  transition: opacity 100ms linear;

Answer (score 3):

Это и делается для кросcбраузерности. Если не хотите все время писать, просто создайте класс типа .br и присваивайте его тем элементам у которых хотите скруглить углы.

```
.text { font-family: /*...*/; color: /*...*/; /*и так далее*/ }
.br { /*тут ваш стиль скругленных углов*/ }

<p class="text br">Some long text</p>
```

Comment: тут вопрос не в том, что у не хочу писать, а в том, нужно ли это еще, есть ли в этом смысл.  
то есть, всё-таки лучше писать набор свойств с префиксами?

Comment: Нужно писать свойста с префиксами.

Comment: спасибо. а то мне сказали, что это уже лишнее, поэтому и спрашиваю, что не знаю, как правильно.

Answer (score 2):

Существует скрипт -Prefix-free (и подобные), который автоматически подставляет префиксы.
Описание: [второй пункт](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137670/)

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю.

Answer (score 0):

Для осла IE8, IE7 есть специальные файлы .htc, которые решают эти проблемы.